# Oracle get last weekday Mon-Fri

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to obtain the last weekday.
If it's Tues to Sat, it will be the previous day. If it's Sunday or Monday, it will be Friday.

So far, I've tried this, but I'm struggling to get the desired output.

```
SELECT
    level AS dow,
    trunc(sysdate, 'D') + level day,
    to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'D') + level, 'Day') AS day_week,
    CASE
        WHEN to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'D') + level, 'Day') IN (
            'Sunday',
            'Monday'
        ) THEN
            trunc(sysdate - 2, 'IW') + 4
        ELSE
            sysdate - 1
    END calculation
FROM
    dual
CONNECT BY
    level <= 7;
```

Comment: Result of `trunc(sysdate, 'D')` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY` setting. Better use `IW` as proposed by MT0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works independent of language and territory:

```sql
SELECT date_value,
       date_value - CASE TRUNC(date_value) - TRUNC(date_value, 'IW')
                    WHEN 0 THEN 3 -- Monday
                    WHEN 6 THEN 2 -- Sunday
                    ELSE 1        -- Tuesday to Saturday
                    END AS previous_weekday
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_value) AS
SELECT TRUNC(sysdate - LEVEL + 1)
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;
```

Outputs (with the date format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (DY)`):

> | DATE_VALUE | PREVIOUS_WEEKDAY |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-07-20 00:00:00 (TUE) | 2021-07-19 00:00:00 (MON) |
> | 2021-07-19 00:00:00 (MON) | 2021-07-16 00:00:00 (FRI) |
> | 2021-07-18 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2021-07-16 00:00:00 (FRI) |
> | 2021-07-17 00:00:00 (SAT) | 2021-07-16 00:00:00 (FRI) |
> | 2021-07-16 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2021-07-15 00:00:00 (THU) |
> | 2021-07-15 00:00:00 (THU) | 2021-07-14 00:00:00 (WED) |
> | 2021-07-14 00:00:00 (WED) | 2021-07-13 00:00:00 (TUE) |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c55281ac4ab2224ade1af772dbe6de5d)*